# Search in Lucene.Net

Tags: .net, lucene

I am using Lucene.NET for the first time and a little confused. I am actually looking to stem word or words in phrase and search for them with all the possibilities with declensions and conjugations.

For example if I search for "runs", it should stem the word to "run" which it does. But also look for "ran", "jog" etc.

Can I have adjectives and all forms of verbs etc be determined in my search?

Comment: "jog" is not a declension or conjugation of "run".  It's a synonym, and a pretty loose one, at that.

Comment: you could use synonyms for run - jogging or whatever you want. runs -> run could be achieved with stemming algorithm